# selenium chrome driver explicit wait is not working

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I am using selenium 2 and a chrome driver and cannot seem to get the explicit wait to work no matter what I do. I am trying to click on an element which generates some data dynamically via ajax (no reloads) and then search for an element when it becomes present on the page.

This is my code

```
        leagueNameItem.Click();

        IList<IWebElement> outerTables_forEachLeague = new List<IWebElement>();

        var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        outerTables_forEachLeague = wait.Until<IList<IWebElement>>((d) =>
        {
            return d.FindElements(By.ClassName("boxVerde"));
        });
```

The element is not found (and it is on the page for sure). The wait function does not actually 'wait' for the 10 seconds as specified ut just returns nothing. Any ideas pls?

Comment: yes they would be found with a bad wait of 1 or 2 seconds...there is nothing else wrong with it as I have tried it...just the wait is not working ...

Comment: I would assume that since `.FindElements` returns an empty list if it cannot find anything, it is just returning. What about if you make it a `.FindElement`, does this return *something*?

Answer (score 10):

The problem is that `FindElements` returns immediately, and returns a valid empty list object if the elements aren't found. You have two choices. You can use a single `FindElement` in your wait, which throws an exception if the element doesn't exist. The `WebDriverWait` object will catch that exception and retry until the element can be found.

However, since you want to return a list from your wait, you'll need to be a little more clever, which leads to your second option. Change your wait to look something like this:

```
leagueNameItem.Click();

IList<IWebElement> outerTables_forEachLeague = new List<IWebElement>();

var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
outerTables_forEachLeague = wait.Until<IList<IWebElement>>((d) =>
{
    var elements = d.FindElements(By.ClassName("boxVerde"));
    if (elements.Count == 0)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return elements;
});
```